# $T(n) = 2T(n-2) + 1$ recursion tree

Tags: recursion

Can someone help me build what the recursion tree would look like for this problem? 
Would the next level be $n-3$, and then $n-4$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like moving the extra term to the front when solving these kinds of problems.
$$\begin{align}
T(n)&=1+2T(n-2)\\
&=1+2(1+2T(n-4))=1+2+4T(n-4)\\
&=1+2+4(1+2T(n-6))=1+2+4+8T(n-6)=\dots\\
&=(2^{n/2}-1)+2^{n/2}T(0)\\
&=\Theta(2^{n/2})
\end{align}$$

Comment: What if the equation was T(n) = 2T(n-4) + 1 would the next level in the tree be (n-8) and then (n-12) ? @ParclyTaxel

Comment: @LucyJones Yeah, something like that, and it'd be $\Theta(2^{n/4})$.

Comment: But shouldn't the answer be Big Theta (2^n) how are you getting Big Theta (2^n/2)

Comment: @LucyJones Yeah, it should be $\Theta(2^n)$ for the modified one.

Comment: Ok, and for this equation T(n) = 2T(n-4) +1 for the modified version it would still be Big Theta (2^n) right?

Comment: @LucyJones Yes.

Answer (score 0):

Let $T(n)=2^{\frac{n}{2}}. A(n)$
$$. $$
Hence $T(n-2)=2^{\frac{n-2}{2}}.A(n-2)$  put in given equation we get
$$2^{\frac{n}{2}}A(n)=2^{\frac{n}{2}}A(n-2)+1$$
$$\therefore A(n)-A(n-2)=2^{-\frac{n}{2}}$$
$$\sum_{n=2}^{n} (A(n)-A(n-2))=\frac{2^{\frac{n-1}{2}}-1}{2^{\frac{n}{2}}}=y \,(say)$$
Hence $ A(n)+A(n-1)-A(0)-A(1)=y$
$$T(n).2^{-\frac{n}{2}}+T(n-1).2^{-\frac{n-1}{2}}=y+T(0)+\frac{T(1)}{\sqrt{2}}$$